# how to store 2dimensional array in shared preferences in android or serialize it

Tags: android, serialization, sharedpreferences

```
i am developing an android app where i have to save dates (* as given in array)
i am doing this by using shared preferences 
my code is working fine but it do some different behaviour which i dont know why
  a.> when i am saving array in shared prefrences it works perfect as i want but 
  b.> when it comes to fetching data it keeps single date  if the date occurs twice in      array ex.. 24 occurs 2 times in my array but on fetching it show me single 24
  c.> also it gives me unordered representation of array 

 i dont know why this is happening and how to solve it 
 **some one told me to use serialize but i dont know how to do this? **    
    String[][] my_date;
    my_date = new String[][] {
                {"14","26"},
                {"12","16","24","27"},
                {"17"},
                {"8","13","18"},
                {"14"},
                {},
                {"29"},
                {"15","18"},
                {},
                {"2","3","6","8","23"},
                {"4","6","24"},
                {}
        };

    /* storing the data in shared preferences */
        SharedPreferences pref = arg0.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
               for(int i=0; i<my_date.length;i++){
                   for(int j =0; j<my_date[i].length;j++){
                       set.add("'"+my_date[i][j]+"'"); 
                       Log.v("dates",my_date[i][j]);
                   }
               }
               editor.putStringSet("dates", set);
               editor.commit();

/* fetching saved data */
     set=pref.getStringSet("dates", set);
     Log.v("dates",set+"----"+set.size());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: This is a kind of a bad idea. You'd probably rather want to store things in a way so that you can make partial edits of them, eg. like using your own custom `SQLLite` database.

But if you're fine with the hacky approach, and you want to store that multi-dimension array in shared preferences, you could probably just serialize it to a string and store the string in the shared prefs.

You might just borrow pieces from this example of how to serialize a thing to a string:
[Reliably convert any object to String and then back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887197/reliably-convert-any-object-to-string-and-then-back-again)

And then take that string and store it in the shared prefs.

**Edit:** Oh well, I was curious so I tried it out.. I actually found I had to base64 encode the string as well, and I wish I could explain why in a cohesive manner, but this is roughly what I did:

```
private void mySharedPreferencesThing() {
    String[][] before = new String[][] {{"1","2","3"}, {}, {"4","5","6"}};

    System.out.println("String thing before: " + arrayToString(before));

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("lolcats", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String[][] after = null;
    try {
        sp.edit().putString("cats", twoDimensionalStringArrayToString(before)).commit();
        after = stringToTwoDimensionalStringArray(sp.getString("cats", null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("String thing after: " + arrayToString(after));
}

// Just for debugging and knowing that it looks correct - there may be
// something built in to do this
private String arrayToString(String[][] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.append("\t{" + TextUtils.join(", ", arr[i]) + "}");
        if (i != arr.length - 1) { sb.append(","); }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}

private String twoDimensionalStringArrayToString(String[][] s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = null;
    ObjectOutputStream so = null;
    Base64OutputStream b64 = null;
    try {
        bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b64 = new Base64OutputStream(bo, Base64.DEFAULT);
        so = new ObjectOutputStream(b64);
        so.writeObject(s);
        return bo.toString("UTF-8");
    } finally {
        if (bo != null) { bo.close(); }
        if (b64 != null) { b64.close(); }
        if (so != null) { so.close(); }
    }
}

private String[][] stringToTwoDimensionalStringArray(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bi = null;
    ObjectInputStream si = null;
    Base64InputStream b64 = null;
    try {
        byte b[] = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
        bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        b64 = new Base64InputStream(bi, Base64.DEFAULT);
        si = new ObjectInputStream(b64);
        return (String[][]) si.readObject();
    } finally {
        if (bi != null) { bi.close(); }
        if (b64 != null) { b64.close(); }
        if (si != null) { si.close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am very close to my destination but didnt know how to implement the code

Comment: I edited my answer by handing you the code on a silver platter :) I think that works. Good luck!

Comment: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("lolcats", MODE_PRIVATE);   can u explain this  "MODE_PRIVATE" is giving me error

Comment: sorry, change that to context.getSharedPreferences("lolcats", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` -- see for reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE

You have the same thing in your example, just with a hard coded 0