# invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF when converting object from byte string

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a ArrayList object to a byte string so it can be sent via sockets. When I run this code it converts to a string properly but when I try to convert it back I get the exception "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF". Other answers I looked at on here didn't really help as I am using the matching ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. Sorry if there is a simple fix as I am new to working with stream objects.

```
try {
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        text.add("Hello World!");
        String byteString = Utils.StringUtils.convertToByteString(text);
        ArrayList<String> convertedSet = (ArrayList<String>) Utils.StringUtils.convertFromByteString(byteString);
        VCS.getServiceManager().addConsoleLog(convertedSet.get(0));
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static String convertToByteString(Object object) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
            out.writeObject(object);
            final byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
            return new String(byteArray);
        }
    }

public static Object convertFromByteString(String byteString) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final byte[] bytes = byteString.getBytes();
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
            return in.readObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: All byte sequences are not valid character sequences in your platform default encoding. Don't transform arbitrary bytes to String. Just use arrays of bytes. If you really need something printable, then use base64 encoding to transform your byte arrays into printable strings. Read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Thanks for the article, it was a good read and helps me understand encoding more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String is not a container for binary data. You need to pass around the original byte array, or hex- or base64-encode it.

Better still, serialize directly to the socket and get rid of this altogether.

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out. I had to use Base64 encoding. The conversion methods have to be changed to the following:

```
public static String convertToByteString(Object object) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
            out.writeObject(object);
            final byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
        }
    }

public static Object convertFromByteString(String byteString) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(byteString);
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
            return in.readObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn’t *have* to use base-64. There are several simpler alternatives.

Comment: You would read my answe that had already been there for three months when you asked.