# How to Serialized my class objects using kotlin?

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, deserialization

i have fragment and i need to pass my values Constructor to OncretaeView() methods so i receive my values in constructor and tr to convert my objects to serialized one but it does not convert. Here is my code. Please guide me how to Serialize and deserialize my objects .
Thanks in advance

```
import java.io.Serializable

class SendingFragment: Fragment(),Serializable {
companion object {
        /**
         * new instance pattern for fragment
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(myObject: List<TransactionEntity>?, cc: Context, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection): SendingFragment {

            val gson = Gson()
            val gson1 = GsonBuilder().create()
            val model = myObject as List<TransactionEntity>
            val IT = gson.toJson(model)
            System.out.println("json representation :" + IT)

            val bo = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val so = ObjectOutputStream(bo)
            so.writeObject(appDatabase)
            so.flush()
            val serializedObject = String(Base64.encode(bo.toByteArray()))

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("bundleValue", IT)
            bundle.putSerializable("serializedObject",serializedObject)
            val sendFragament: SendingFragment = SendingFragment()
            sendFragament.setArguments(bundle)
            return sendFragament
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val mFragserializedObject = arguments!!.getSerializable("serializedObject")
        System.out.println( "json serializedObject" + mFragserializedObject)
    }
}
```

**Appdatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = {AddressBookEntry.class, Token.class, Balance.class, TransactionEntity.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({RoomTypeConverters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract AddressBookDAO getAddressBook();

    public abstract TokenDAO getTokens();

    public abstract TransactionDAO getTransactions();

    public abstract BalanceDAO getBalances();
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
class BeanDemo : Serializable {

    var MyAppDatabase: AppDatabase ? = null

    constructor() {

    }

    //secoutry constructor

    constructor(appDatabase: AppDatabase){
        this. MyAppDatabase =  appDatabase
        Log.d("appDatabase : Bean", "appDatabase$appDatabase")
    }

    //getter/setter methods

    fun getName(): AppDatabase? {
        Log.d("appDatabase : getName", "appDatabase$MyAppDatabase")
        return MyAppDatabase
    }

    fun setName(NEWAPPDB: AppDatabase) {
        Log.d("appDatabase : NEWAPPDB", "appDatabase$NEWAPPDB")
        MyAppDatabase = NEWAPPDB
    }
}

**myfragent.kt**



 fun newInstance(myObject: List<TransactionEntity>?, cc: Context, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection): SendingFragment {

                val gson = Gson()
                val gson1 = GsonBuilder().create()
                val model = myObject as List<TransactionEntity>
                val IT = gson.toJson(model)
    //             Here
                val sampleVar = BeanDemo(appDatabase)
                sampleVar.setName(appDatabase)
 val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("bundleValue", IT)
            bundle.putSerializable("serializedObject",sampleVar)
            val sendFragament: SendingFragment = SendingFragment()
            sendFragament.setArguments(bundle)
            return sendFragament

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {



        val bundle = arguments
        val obj = bundle!!.getSerializable("serializedObject") as BeanDemo
        val name = obj.getName()

        }
```

But **val obj =** is null, in setter method to hold the value but does not return it.

Comment: How's your data class? can you post it?

Comment: sure @Skizo-ozᴉʞS check my cquestion

Comment: What do youl want to be Serializable????

Comment: Karthikeyan , check my answer with example below

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS then how can i pass the values to Oncreateview() method ???

Comment: sure i will check and update to you @Thunder

Comment: Don't use Serializable on Android, it has a more efficient way of doing that: Parcellable and it's even really easy to use in kotlin: e.g. https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac - btw when you create a string as your serialization, you have to use `putString` / `getString` not serializable.

Comment: but how to do with fragment because in fragmentwe can not use INtent then how to pass ??

Answer (score 3):

When you create your `Model/POJO` class, then `extend` the `class` with `Serializable`.

*Example-*

```
class JsonData : Serializable {

    @SerializedName("hasPreviousData")
    var hasPreviousData: Boolean = false

    @SerializedName("dataList")
    var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>? = null

    inner class DataList : Serializable {
        @SerializedName("id")
        var id: String? = null
        @SerializedName("createdAt")
        var createdAt: String? = null
        @SerializedName("name")
        var name: String? = null
    }
}
```

Comment: once you store your data in a POJO/Model like this then you can access that in your activity/fragment

Comment: have a doubt ,  the result come up with look like this "AppdatabaseIMP@43b8de6 " how can i convert this ??? is your idea can be done this ???

Comment: i can refer this site can you plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887197/reliably-convert-any-object-to-string-and-then-back-again/8887244#8887244

Comment: give me few mins

Comment: sure ,  please . .

Comment: do you have Gson dependency added in your project ?

Comment: yes . . i can check that with gson but i was not able to convert into tojson()

Comment: add this log      
   Log.d("JsonDataValue", "data is=" + Gson().toJson(your_variable))

Comment: your_variable is the value where you storing the jsonobject data

Comment: okay you can tell what can i do with GSON may be you think like a unique way

Comment: first try to check if data is printing in your logs and let me know

Comment: just put this log Log.d("JsonDataValue", "data is=" + Gson().toJson(mFragserializedObject))

Comment: App stoped when reach this line "so.writeObject(appDatabase)"

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl
 at                                                                        com.crypto.wallet.activities.SendingFragment$Companion.newInstance(SendingFragment.kt:65)

Comment: this answer actually tells you how to serialize a json model class in Kotlin , feel free to accept this answer

Comment: How to do that ?? explain little bit more

Comment: kindly check the answer properly

Comment: sure bro . .i will

Comment: here is the way how you can accept this answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I will check with your answer and apply same functinality but i have some problem while getting data plz check my update @Thunder