# How to store JSON Array inside List in java?

Tags: java, json, list

I'm passing json array from angularjs, and it's comes on Spring Controller, I catch it there at **@RequestBody String data**

I want to store those data inside List,

I tried this,

```
List<RegisterDTO> stdList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterDTO>(data);
```

But I don't know **JsonConvert** from where it's coming? I'm getting an error there(cannot to be resolved).

RegisterController.java

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerStudent.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean registerStudent(@RequestBody String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    if (stdList != null) {
        // store stdList
    }
    return registerService.isStudentExist(stdList);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java code corresponding to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object source,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()) in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622049/java-code-corresponding-to-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-serializeobjectobject-so)

Comment: it's in .net.?..... i'm using java. so, what should i use ?

Comment: That is exactly what the dup asks: What is Java's equivalent of JsonConvert?

Answer (score 0):

So What you have provided is example of Newtonsoft JSON.net used for c#

For Java you have to use different libraries.

Like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Here is an example on [How to deserialize json string into object in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860614/how-to-deserialize-json-string-into-object)